# SQL, Case When returning the incorrect results

Tags: sql-server

This error is starting to tick me off so im posting pictures instead sorry......

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is just lazy... Read the bloody error message that's *literally in your screenshot*!  You didn't format your code, and it's quite literally a single button press to do so.  It even tells you *exactly* how to do it!

Comment: Good grief...those nested case expressions could be simplified into a single case expression.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, the expression `some-value = NULL` always returns `NULL`, which is logically a lot like false.  What you want is `some-value IS NULL`